# how to add point to label of coresponding points button

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have one label called `pacak.label`. It will have the point based on the user database. And below that pacak.label we have 4 buttons. like:

```
 1. +20
 2. +50
 3. +100
 4. +200
```

So for example: IF my `Pacak.label is = 20` means. when user press any `4 button below`. like says if user press `+50 button means` then my `pacak.label points` should goes `from 20 to 70`. Like wise if user press again any button like says `+20 means` . my `pacak.label` button should goes from `70 to 90`. Like wise whenever user press any value button that particular button value should be added and display in my Packa.label.

My button action:

```
-(IBAction)+20ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
}

-(IBAction)+50ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
}

-(IBAction)+100ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    }

-(IBAction)+200ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
}
```

Kindly help me to do that . i am new to ios. Not able to do that calculation,THnaks

Answer (score 2):

If I understanded well, you want to increase score depending which button is tapped. First, you need value called score, or something like that: `NSInteger score;` then, you need to call score increase on every button action:

```
-(IBAction)+20ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
        score+=20;
    pacak.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
            }

   -(IBAction)+50ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
        score+=50;
    pacak.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
            }

  -(IBAction)+100ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
        score+=100;
    pacak.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
                }

 -(IBAction)+200ButtonTapped:(id)sender {
        score+=200;
    pacak.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];       
     }
```

Comment: ok if my pacak.label is already having 20. so if i press +50 button by using your code. does my pacak.label will goes fro 20 to 70??

Comment: You must consider one thing, label is only showing values, you must have property that will save value, in this case score... And label is showing that score. And yes, it will go from 20 to 70...